# Possible to determine if user has clicked on ANY notification (not just from my app) in real time?

Tags: java, android

I'm making my first Android app. Is it possible to listen to any commands that is triggered when a user clicks on any notification? I don't need to know which notification that was clicked, just the fact that any notification was clicked on.

Maybe it's possible to listen to FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL or similar.

I'm a beginner, so please excuse me if I'm not clear enough or using the wrong vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

When a notification is clicked the [ContentIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent) is executed and that's it, there will not be a Broadcast that a notification has been clicked.

So to answer the question, it's not possible

Comment: Thank you @Sander

Can you think of any workaraounds for this issue? For instance, most notifications are removed from the notification center when they have been clicked. Is there any way to know when a notification is being removed?

Comment: Another option might be to listen if any apps are being opened straight from the lock screen. That suggests that the app was open from clicking on a notification.

Comment: Maybe listen for [MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event.html#MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND)